# Parse SOAP Message using STAX

Tags: xml, soap, stax

I have written the following code to Parse SOAP message using STAX. I am getting null pointer exception at xmlStreamReader.hasNext(). Please help.

```
    Source src = soapMsg.getSOAPPart().getContent();
    ...
    HorizonHeaderData header = parser.parseHorizonHeader(src);
    ...
    public HorizonHeaderData parseHorizonHeader(Source src) {
    HorizonHeaderData header = new HorizonHeaderData();
    XMLInputFactory xmlInputFactory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
    if (null != src) {

        try {
            XMLStreamReader xmlStreamReader = xmlInputFactory.createXMLStreamReader(src);


            if(xmlStreamReader==null){
                System.out.println("xmlStreamReader is null");
            }

            while(xmlStreamReader.hasNext()){
                int event = xmlStreamReader.getEventType();
                switch(event){
                case XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT:
                        System.out.println("Element: "+ xmlStreamReader.getLocalName() + "\nValue: "+ xmlStreamReader.getElementText());
                }

                xmlStreamReader.next();
```

The input XML is

```html
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:bpel="http://xmlns.oracle.com/TestLoggingComposite/SSNService/BPELProcess2">
   <soapenv:Header>
    <oas:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="0" xmlns:oas="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:soap="soap" xmlns:xsi="xsi">
         <wsu:SecurityContextToken xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-secureconversation/200512">
            <wsu:Identifier>${=java.util.UUID.randomUUID()}</wsu:Identifier>
         </wsu:SecurityContextToken>
      </oas:Security>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body/>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I am able see the values using DOM but there is exception using STAX. Kindly help.

Comment: why sax? it is a notoriously bad processing model, hard to use, long tedious code...

Comment: We needed to process the headers in the fastest way.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include a description of your app logic? IE. what your code tries to accomplish, I can then submit something for you to consider...